# Mordechai's ban on going to Achashveirosh's party

Tags: sources-mekorot, megillat-esther, parties-celebrations

Is there a source that Mordechai banned or prohibited the Jews from going to Achashveirosh's party?

Comment: if you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 7):

The source is Medrash Esther Rabba 7:13

See [here](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/ester/7a-2.htm#9):

> אמר רבי יצחק נפחא המן הרשע בעלילה גדולה בא על ישראל הה"ד ובמלאת הימים האלה עשה המלך לכל העם הנמצאים בשושן הבירה וגו' ואין העם האמור כאן אלא ישראל הה"ד (דברים ל"ג) אשריך ישראל מי כמוך עם נושע בה' וגו', אמר המן לאחשורוש אלהיהם של אלו שונא זמה העמד להם זונות ועשה להם משתה וגזר עליהם שיבואו כולם ויאכלו וישתו ויעשו כרצונם שנאמר לעשות כרצון איש ואיש, כיון שראה מרדכי כך עמד והכריז עליהם ואמר להם לא תלכו לאכול בסעודתו של אחשורוש שלא הזמין אתכם כי אם ללמד עליכם קטיגוריא כדי שיהא פתחון פה עם מדת הדין לקטרג עליכם לפני הקב"ה ולא שמעו לדברי מרדכי והלכו כולם לבית המשתה

Translation:

> Rabbi Yitzchak Nafcha said: "The wicked Haman came upon Israel with a great scheme, as it is written ([*Esther* 1:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3301.htm#5)), 'And with the completion of these days, the king made a feast of seven days for the entire nation ("*l'chol ha'am*") who were to be found in [Shushan the capital](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6006), from great to small.' And the 'nation' mentioned here refers to none other than Israel, as it is written ([*D'varim* 33:29](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0533.htm#29)), 'Fortunate are you Israel, who is like you, a nation saved by HaShem, etc.'
>
> "Haman said to Achashveirosh, 'Their God hates promiscuity. Provide prostitutes for them, make them a feast, and decree upon them that they all come and eat and drink and do as they will.' As the verse states ([*Esther* 1:8](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3301.htm#8)), 'to do according to each man's will.'
>
> "As soon as Mordechai saw this, he arose and proclaimed over them and said to them, 'Do not go to eat at the feast of Achashveirosh, for he invited you only to create a prosecution against you, so that the Attribute of Justice will have an opening to prosecute against you before the Holy One Blessed be He.' But they did not heed the words of Mordechai, and they all went to the banquet hall."